# atom feed xmlns attribute messes up AS3's XML-parsing?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing, rss, xml-namespaces

Wanna see something interesting?

```
var xml:XML = XML(<feed><entry /><entry /><entry /></feed>);
trace(xml.entry.length())   // returns 3
```

Makes sense, right? Now let's add this attribute...

```
var xml:XML = XML(<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><entry /><entry /><entry /></feed>);
trace(xml.entry.length())   // returns 0
```

Well that can't be right. Let's try it with a different attribute.

```
var xml:XML = XML(<feed test="okay"><entry /><entry /><entry /></feed>);
trace(xml.entry.length())   // returns 3
```

Anyone know what would cause this? I used atom as an example, but any 'xmlns' attribute on the root node seems to have this effect. The value returned is straight up false - there are obviously still 3 'entry' child nodes regardless of the attributes their parents possess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are possible workarounds:

```
var xml:XML = XML(<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><entry /><entry /><entry /></feed>) ;
trace(xml.entry.length()) ;
// output: 0

var ATOM:Namespace = new Namespace( "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" );
trace(xml.ATOM::entry.length()) ;
// output: 3

default xml namespace = ATOM;
trace(xml.entry.length()) ;
// output: 3
```

**Update**

[LiveDocs.Adobe.Com](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000130.html)

Comment: Nice, apparently we came to the same conclusion at the same time. I'll let you have the 'accepted answer,' though.

Comment: another thing you can do to shortcut it a bit is -

var atom:Namespace = xml.namespace() // picks up the default
trace(xml.atom::entry.length()) ;

... and the advantage of this is that it'll work even if there are no namespaces defined, which is pretty cool.