# AS3: doesn't read Atom

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, atom-feed

I want to read an Atom in Flex.
I can see in the debugger that he can read the Atom and that there are entries, I can see each value. So far, so good.

But when I want to assign a value from the atom to a variable, he never gives any text. It's always this: "".

My code:

```
ch.Name = xml.title;
ch.Desc = xml.subtitle;
ch.Updated = xml.updated;

for each(var entry:XML in xml.entry)
{                                           var fee:Feed = new Feed();
fee.Name = entry.title;
fee.Url = entry.link.@href;
fee.Desc = entry.summary;
fee.Updated = entry.updated;
fee.Published = entry.published;

ch.Children.addItem(fee);   
}
```

For example this is the value ch.Name gets

```
ch.Name = "";
```

But that's strange, because I can see in the debugger that it schould be "Tweakers.net".
It becomes even more strange, because it works just fine with RSS.

Thanks a lot,
Vincent

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Could be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112945/atom-feed-xmlns-attribute-messes-up-as3s-xml-parsing ... the question's not exactly the same, but I'm pretty sure the answer is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is related to xml namespaces (defined with the attribute xmlns in your atom xml).

I've never had to work with Atom so I don't have first hand experience, but I remember reading about it a couple of times.

I found [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112945/atom-feed-xmlns-attribute-messes-up-as3s-xml-parsing), which might get you on the right track.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the linked question appears to have the same exact problem as you, and the selected answer should solver your problem.

Comment: I solved it by using httpService instead of URLLoader, but this answer is maybe better.

Answer (score -1):

My best is to trace each node.

Can i have a look into your resultevent and in what format you are getting it.

Comment: My evt.target.data has the format XML. I can view everything from this XML in the debugger, but when i trace everything it is empty.